# classicthesis and titlesec

Tags: titlesec, classicthesis

I'm still trying to make `classicthesis` work. The problem now is that I get lots of warnings about `titlesec`... As a matter of fact, with this preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}


%fonts
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{classicthesis}  
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{lipsum}
```

I get this kind of headers

[image]

I've read about incompatibility between titlesec and KOMA script, but I haven't been able to understand how to fix it. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can (probably) silence the warnings, but that does not fix the fact, that classicthesis is in wide parts incompatible with KOMA-script.

Comment: And `titlesec` is not compatible with KOMA too. I think, there are a lot of questions that deal with this issue and you've been told so already, as far as I can remember

Comment: `classicthesis` assumes the KOMA-option `headinclude` and `footinclude`, else the header will be on the edge of the page.

Comment: `classicthesis` really just defines a bit of the optical appearance. All functionality, chapters, sections, referencing and citing, list generation etc. is basic LaTeX functiionality and available without any template.

Answer (score 4):

I just pretend the question contains questions:

1. What is the warning concerning `titlesec` about?
2. Why are my headers looking horrible?

---

1) The `classicthesis` template uses `scrreprt` with the option `headinclude` and `footinclude`, which are passed over to package `typearea`.

Package `classicthesis` defines the size of the typeblock, ensuring that package `typearea` is loaded, but not taking into account the options passed to it. So you have to always add the options globally. Or use package `geometry` to change the margins, which makes using the package `classicthesis` pointless, as it only defines the style.

2) Opposed to it, the author of `classicthesis` decided to tweak the appearance of sectional headings using package `titlesec`, which in the meantime issues a quite prominent warning by KOMA-script, because it breaks some KOMA functionality.

You can (probably) silence the warnings, but that does not fix the fact, that classicthesis is in wide parts incompatible with KOMA-script.

---

A little example:

```
\documentclass[
%   headinclude,footinclude,% option for tyearea
    headings=optiontoheadandtoc
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{classicthesis}% destroys head/toc mechanism using titlesec
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[head={Walter Wombat}, tocentry={Gerry
Giraffe}]{Lyndon Lizard}% kicked by titlesec
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```